# Signal Processing using Fourier Transform1

Tags: signal-analysis

How can I derive the fourier transform of

```
                                   g1(t) = {A cos(2πfc t),−T/2 < t <T/2
                                            0,               elsewhere
```

and;

```
                                  g2(t) = cos(t), −∞ < t < ∞
```

my answer for `g1` is;

```
    ∫ g(t)exp(-j*2*pi*f*t)dt = ∫ Acos(2*pi*fc*t)exp(-j*2*pi*f*t)dt

       =∫ 1/2A (exp(j*2*pi*fc*t)+exp(-j*2*pi*fc*t))exp(-j*2*pi*f*t)dt

       =∫1/2A(exp(j*2*pi*fc*t)exp(-j*2*pi*fc*t)+∫1/2A(exp        (-j*2*pi*fc*t)exp(-j*2*pi*fc*t))

       =1/2A∫exp(-j*2*pi(f-fc)t) + 1/2A ∫exp(-j*2*pi(f+fc)t)dt

       =1/2A(f-fc)+1/2A(f+fc)
```

Comment: Hello ! If you want to add some details to yiur question, please, edit it, instead of asking a new one.

Comment: oh well I just saw the edit button sorry :D im going to delete it :))